# How can I download photos from a URL of folder in dropbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, dropbox

I have a Rails application which is suppose to upload images from a Dropbox URL pointed to a folder. The folder contains the images. Application is suppose to upload all images present in folder.

The URL is somewhat like this

```
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/17fsm6bsnac1g4q/AADJ7B2L0OIrkSrc7YcG-OO9a?dl=0
```

I can see the images but how can I get the list of all images URL. I have tried parsing the URL by appending `dl=1` which downloads the images.

```
URI.parse('https://www.dropbox.com/sh/17fsm6bsnac1g4q/AADJ7B2L0OIrkSrc7YcG-OO9a?dl=1).
```

How can I get the URL of all images. If I can not get URL of images then how can i download all images and them upload them.

Comment: Did you consider using the [dropbox sdk](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/dropbox-sdk)?

Comment: Dropbox does not have SDK for ruby for v2, it has HTTP endpoints.

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/overview

Comment: I am confused. The link I posted points to the [official dropbox sdk gem for Ruby](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/dropbox-sdk). Quote from the docs: _"A Ruby library that for Dropbox's HTTP-based Core API."_ And you say Dropbox does not have an SDK for Ruby? What do I miss?

Comment: Thank you for sharing link to sdk, but the sdk supports v1 API which is now deprecated by Dropbox. Its written

=====================================================================================================
WARNING: THIS GEM USES THE NOW DEPRECATED V1 API; APPS USING IT WILL NOT BE ACCEPTED INTO PRODUCTION.
=====================================================================================================
More info: https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2016/06/api-v1-deprecated/

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with just downloading everything, you can make a GET request to the `dl=1` version of the link you have. This URL parameter is documented [here](https://www.dropbox.com/help/desktop-web/force-download). This will give you a zipped version of the folder which you can then unzip and use as necessary.

Dropbox doesn't offer a way to get links for each of the files in the linked folder, but you can use the Dropbox API to list the files and then download them individually. You can use [the /2/files/list_folder endpoint](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-list_folder) and pass the shared link in as the `shared_link` parameter. That will give you a list of the items in the folder.

You can then use [/2/sharing/get_shared_link_file](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-get_shared_link_file) to download any desired file(s), by passing in the shared link as the `url` parameter, and the relative path for the file as the `path` parameter.